# Rotate text in Android?

Tags: android

I need to rotate text in Vertical by using Canvas (canvas.drawText).I need to use  that in Barchart.How to do this?

As like a following 
[Image](http://www.google.co.in/imgres?imgurl=http://www.fieldcheckgroup.com/wp-content/uploads/2009/06/nts-bar-chart.png&imgrefurl=http://www.fieldcheckgroup.com/blog/&usg=__BYabhXXIE_IWzgmYAvRpIQdT5OI=&h=382&w=629&sz=14&hl=en&start=97&sig2=zZrKKxYYkcgY85nTmEt3Vg&zoom=1&tbnid=EBWWahP111tD0M:&tbnh=118&tbnw=195&ei=HMoMTYvpBJDWvQPAh5DGDQ&prev=/images%3Fq%3Dbar%2Bchart%26um%3D1%26hl%3Den%26sa%3DN%26rls%3Dig%26biw%3D1024%26bih%3D653%26tbs%3Disch:10,4463&um=1&itbs=1&iact=hc&vpx=536&vpy=143&dur=3148&hovh=175&hovw=288&tx=189&ty=93&oei=4MkMTb3aIIyqrAeUtrTECw&esq=9&page=9&ndsp=12&ved=1t:429,r:6,s:97&biw=1024&bih=653)

Answer (score 1):

`Canvas` has a `rotate()` method that will adjust its orientation for subsequent operations.